# Filter numbers that contains 966 in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a large list of phone numbers that are formatted like this 5XXXXXXXX or this 9665XXXXXXXX.

Anyone know how can I search for the cells that has the numbers '966' in them?

The numbers I want to be shown should look like this 5X966XXXX or 9665XX966XXX.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the phone numbers are in column A. Then enter`=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("966";A1))` in cell B1. Copy B1 down to the end of the list. Now, numbers containing "966" will have TRUE in column B, others FALSE. You can now filter for TRUE in column B to only display matching phone numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below for filtering phone numbers in Excel.

1.) Within Excel click on the top column to highlight all the phone numbers.

2.) Click Data tab in your toolbar.

3.) Click Filter.

You should now have a dropdown box at the top of the column which will provide a search box for filtering.